# Shared memory POSIX put value to string

Tags: c++, posix, shared-memory

I want to create string in shared memory. I have simple program i C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

int main(void){
    std::string* line;
    key_t lineKey = ftok("/tmp", '1');
    int sharedLine = shmget(lineKey, sizeof(std::string), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    line = (std::string*)shmat(sharedLine, NULL, 0);

    std::string helpVar = "";
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> helpVar;
        (*line) = helpVar;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute it (compiling ok when execute `g++ -o myprogram myprogram.cpp -lpthread`) and writing something it says `Core dumped`. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply allocate memory. That is not sufficient. For the start, you need to construct a string object. You can use placement `new` [operator](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) for this purpose, as in:

```
line = new(shmat(sharedLine, NULL, 0)) std::string();
```

However, this will not solve your problems if you want the actual *contents* of the string to be in the shared memory. One way to handle that would be define a custom allocator for a `std::basic_string` class that would use the shared memory pool. On the other hand, it would be too much trouble, and a string object created in this way would be of a different type compared to the standard `std::string`.

Therefore it's better just use plain old C zero-terminated strings:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void){
    key_t lineKey = ftok("/tmp", '2');
    int sharedLine = shmget(lineKey, MAX_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
    char *line = (char *)shmat(sharedLine, NULL, 0);

    std::string helpVar;
    while (true) {
       std::cin >> helpVar;
       strncpy(line, helpVar.c_str(), MAX_SIZE - 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank You, I'm newby in this and I do this stupid mistake :(

Comment: Is that going to work? A string isn't a basic object. It has allocations of its own, that are not going to be in shared memory. Better stick to simple integers (inc. character arrays).